# Auto approve new users if their username is included in a predefined list

Tags: users, user-registration

I need to have users' registration in my website as Subscribers.

Each user will provide a username. I need to have a list that contains a company's usernames and then I need to automatically approve any new user that his/her id is included in that list.

Is there an easy way to that support this procedure?

Comment: Hi Zinon! This community's purpose does not include recommending plugins or themes. It would be pretty easy to support this without a plugin, though. Maybe you could rephrase your question.

Comment: @MikeNGarrett thank you for your feedback. I've updated my question. Can you please help me on this?

Comment: Have you considered scenarios such as a spammer registering using one of those approved company's usernames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might put this code in `functions.php` :

```
$GLOBALS['allowed_users']= ['mikejordan', 'jamesbrown', ...];


add_action('user_register','my_function');
function my_function($user_id){
    // get user data
    $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
    if ( in_array($user_info->login, $GLOBALS['allowed_users'] ) )
    {
       $res = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("SELECT activation_key from {$wpdb->signups} WHERE user_login = %s)", $user_info->login));
       if (!empty($res)) {
          wpmu_activate_signup( $res->activation_key );
       }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use WP-cli to solve your problem there are many tutorials are available for that. But i prefer this blog it is similar to your requirement

https://www.toptal.com/wordpress/automating-with-wp-cli

I have lots of learn from this blog and hopefully you can also learn by this blog.

Thanks me leter.

Comment: Please edit your answer and include relevant code to answer the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may be do like this way

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'check_username_before_register_5565656', 10, 1 );

function check_username_before_register_5565656( $user_id ) {

        $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);

        //put a demo array here, you can pull from db
        $allowed_username = array('test1','test2','test3');

        if ( in_array($user_info->login, $allowed_username ) ) {
                //put you code here which skip the user validation process

            }

        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a few options how you can do this, depending on at which point you want to do the username validation.

**1) Validate username (and email) after (default) registration form has been submitted and before the user is created**

Error messages are shown on the registration page.

```
function my_prefix_registration_errors( $errors, $sanitized_user_login, $user_email ) {
  if ( ! is_valid_username( $sanitized_user_login ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'invalid_username', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid username.', 'my_textdomain' ) );
  }
  if ( ! is_valid_email( $user_email ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'invalid_email', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: Invalid email.', 'my_textdomain' ) );
  }
  return $error;
}
add_filter( 'registration_errors', 'my_prefix_registration_errors', 10, 3 );
```

**2) Validate username when the user is being created with wp_insert_user()**

```
// step 1, validate username
function my_prefix_pre_user_login( $sanitized_user_login ) {
  if ( ! is_valid_username( $sanitized_user_login ) ) {
    $sanitized_user_login = 'illegal_username';
  }
  return $sanitized_user_login;
}
add_filter( 'pre_user_login', 'my_prefix_pre_user_login' );

// step 2, add blocked usernames. If username is invalid after step 1, it will trigger "invalid_username" WP_Error with this filter thus blocking the registration
function my_prefix_illegal_user_logins() {
  return array('illegal_username');
}
add_filter( 'illegal_user_logins', 'my_prefix_illegal_user_logins' );
```

**3) Allow all registrations, but change user role, if illegal username after new registration**

```
function my_prefix_register_new_user( $user_id ) {
  $user = get_user_by( 'ID', $user_id );
  if ( ! is_valid_username( $user->user_login ) ) {
    $user->set_role('invalid_registration');
  }
}
add_filter( 'register_new_user', 'my_prefix_register_new_user' );
```

**4) Building upon T.Toduas answer regardin multisite user activation.**

Activation without the use of `$GLOBALS`.

```
function t_toduas_user_register_function($user_id){
  // get user data
  $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
  if ( is_valid_username( $user_info->login ) ) {
    $res = get_activation( $user_info->login );
    if ( !empty( $res ) ) {
      wpmu_activate_signup( $res->activation_key );
    }
  }
}
add_action('user_register','t_toduas_user_register_function');
```

---

Helper functions for the examples above

```
function get_allowed_usernames() {
  return array(
    'donald',
    'goofy'
    'mickey'
  );
}

function get_valid_domain() {
  return 'example.com';
}

function is_valid_username( $username ) {
  return in_array( $username, get_allowed_usernames() );
}

// crude email validation
function is_valid_email( $email ) {
  if ( is_email( $email ) ) {
    return false;
  }
  $email_pieces = explode( '@', $email );
  return in_array( get_valid_domain(), $email_pieces );
}

function get_activation( $login ) {
  global $wpdb;
  return $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("SELECT activation_key from {$wpdb->signups} WHERE user_login = %s)", $login));
}
```